# What is the time complexity and space complexity of this algorithm to find Anagrams?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am working on an interview question from [Amazon Software](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Amazon-com-Software-Development-Engineer-Intern-Interview-Questions-EI_IE6036.0,10_KO11,47_IP7.htm)
The question is 
"Design an algorithm to take a list of strings as well as a single input string, and return the indices of the list which are anagrams of the input string, disregarding special characters."
I was able to design the algorithm fine, what I did in psuedo code was 
1.Create an array character count of the single input string
2.For each string the list, construct the an array character count
3.Compare the character count of each string in list to single output string
4.If same, add it to a list that holds all the indexes of anagrams. 
5.Return that list of indices.

Here is my implementation in Java(it works, tested it)

```
public static List<Integer> indicesOfAnag(List<String> li, String comp){
    List<Integer> allAnas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[] charCounts = generateCharCounts(comp);
    int listLength = li.size();
    for(int c=0;c<listLength; c++ ){ 
        int[] charCountComp = generateCharCounts(li.get(c));
        if(isEqualCounts(charCounts, charCountComp))
            allAnas.add(c);
    }
    return allAnas;
}
private static boolean isEqualCounts(int[] counts1, int[] counts2){
    for(int c=0;c<counts1.length;c++) {
        if(counts1[c]!=counts2[c]) 
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
private static int[] generateCharCounts(String comp) {
    int[] charCounts = new int[26];
    int length = comp.length();
    for(int c=0;c<length;c++) {
        charCounts[Character.toLowerCase(comp.charAt(c)) - 'a'] ++;
    }
    return charCounts;
}
```

What I am having trouble with is analyzing the space and time complexity of this algorithm because of both of the sizes of the list and of each string.
 Would the time complexity algorithm just be O(N) where N is the size of the list(processing each String once) or do I have to take into account the composite complexity of the length of each String, in that case, O(N * n) where n is the length of the string? I did N * n because you ware processing n N times. And would space complexity be O(N) because I am creating N copies of the 26 length array?

Comment: I dont think its too broad. Theres one answer for space and time complexity.....

Comment: If the underlying implementation of `List<String>` passed in to `indicesOfAnag(...)` is a `LinkedList`, then the `li.get(c)` will be O(N) and the whole thing becomes quadratic in the size of the input.  Better overall to use an iterator to avoid this.

Comment: @msandiford so this is an example of O(N^2) ? just wondering because im learning about this this semester.

Comment: @JRowan If you see the answer below, with arraylist, it should be O(N) where N is the sum of all the lengths of strings

Comment: so the time complexity is linear?

Comment: I think so with respect to total length of all strings. @msandiford can you confirm?

Comment: @JRowan but anways developing Android Apps is so much more fun than this haha

Comment: @committedandroider, haha, yeah i been at it 2 years trying to find that needle in a haystack , school is my backup plan

Comment: @JRowan, based on the implementation shown, it can be either O(N^2) or O(N) depending on the type of `List` passed in.

Comment: @msandiford if you used a LinkedList, you're iterating just over n over and over again, the number of strings, not N, the total number of characters, so wouldn't the runtime be O(n + M)?

Comment: OK, I'm getting confused by use of 'N', 'n' and 'm'.  If 'N' is the number of elements in the `li` argument to `indicesOfAnag`, then the `for (int c =...` loop is O(N).  The `for` loop has a `li.get(c)` embedded in it, which is also an O(N) operation for a linked list, so total time is O(N*N). This is pretty much the classic structure for O(N^2) complexity algorithms.  My point was that given the implementation, the complexity could vary depending on the actual types of the arguments.

Comment: @msandiford wouldn't you have to take into account the length of the strings? So you have to have two variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And would space complexity be O(N) because I am creating N copies of the 26 length array?

Yes.

> Would the time complexity algorithm just be O(N) where N is the size of the list

No. Time depends on size of input strings, it'll be O(comp.length+sum_of_li_lengths).

Comment: Wouldn't it just be N * n, where n is the average length of a string? I don't get why you added comp.length and sum_of_li_lengths.

Comment: Nope, it wouldn't. Strings in `li` can all contain only one character, but `li` can contain millions of strings. That's what called *input data size* in complexity theory.

Comment: oh so you included two variables in your analysis because the runtime depends on both of them? But why do the sum of all the lengths? Each time N runs, it's just going to look at one String.

Comment: Sorry, i missed smth in your question. In your case time complexity doesn't depend on size of the list. It depends only on total length of all your strings. This is because every symbol is handled once.

Comment: I know it has to depend on the size of the list. Theres a for loop that ends at the size of the list. The algorithm will scale up linearly with size.

Comment: Think yourself: will your algorithm work faster on one string of size 1000000 or 100000 strings of size 10? If you know that your code works, you could write simple benchmarks to check it.

Comment: The same. Because they both evaluate to 1000000?

Comment: Exactly. If each symbol is handled once, time complexity will grow linearly with every symbol in input.